# Javaee, postgresql and tomcat

Tags: java, postgresql, tomcat, servlets

I'm studing javaee and Im executing the project in ubuntu server with tomcat and postgres.
When I try to execute the servlet , I have this error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.EntityTransaction
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1718)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1569)
    ejemploLoginMVC.Modelo.Conexion.crearla(Conexion.java:50)
    ejemploLoginMVC.Controller.nuevoUsuario.doPost(nuevoUsuario.java:47)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
```

usuario.java

```
@Entity

public class Usuario {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id_Usuario;
    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String nick;
    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String password;

    public String getNick() {
        return nick;
    }
    public void setNick(String nick) {
        this.nick = nick;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }



}
```

Conexion.java

```
public class Conexion {

    private static EntityManagerFactory emf;
    private static EntityManager em;
    private static EntityTransaction tx;

    String nick;
    String pass;
    public Conexion(String nick,String pass){
        this.nick=nick;
        this.pass=pass;
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public static void initEntityManager() throws Exception {
        emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("usuarios-unit");
        em = emf.createEntityManager();
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void closeEntityManager() throws SQLException {
        if (em != null) em.close();
        if (emf != null) emf.close();
    }

    @Before
    public void initTransaction() {
        tx = em.getTransaction();
    }

    public void crearla() throws Exception{

        Usuario usuario=new Usuario();
        usuario.setNick(nick);
        usuario.setPassword(pass);

        tx.begin();
        em.persist(usuario);
        tx.commit();

        em.close();
        emf.close();
    }

}
```

nuevoUsuario.java (servlet)

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

String nick = request.getParameter("nick");
String pass = request.getParameter("pass");
Conexion conexion= new Conexion(nick,pass);
try {
    conexion.crearla();
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
try(PrintWriter out =response.getWriter()){

    out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
    out.println("<html>");
    out.println("<head>");
    out.println("</head>");
    out.println("<body>");
    out.println("<p>USUARIO:"+nick+"</p>");
    out.println("<p>PASSWORD:"+pass+"</p>");

    out.println("</body>");
    out.println("</html>");
```

}

I cant find the error, i added to the project: postgresql-jdbc4.jar , javaee-api-6.0 , tomcat jars , tomee jars ,etc

Thanks :D

Comment: Did you include all JARs that you have added to your project in your IDE also in your WAR when deploying it to your tomcat? The exception states that it is missing a JPA interface. Since Tomcat (as oppossed to TomEE) does not ship with JPA, you have to make sure to add the JPA jars either to your web applications lib folder or add them to Tomcat's lib folder.

Comment: thanks , do you know where is the folder ? I cant find it . I have in /var/lib/tomcat7 : common conf logs server shared webapss work but I dont know where I have to put the jars files.

Comment: It should be the tomcat7/lib folder. Be aware that in this case all your other web applications will also have that lib on their classpath, but it seems like you have currently only one web app deployed.

Comment: I found the folder , is in /usr/share/tomcat7/lib , thanks beosign!

Comment: If it has helped, it would also be useful for others to see that the answer has been accepted and was hepful :)

Answer (score 0):

To summarize the comments to the question:

The `ClassNotFoundException` is thrown because the JPA related classes cannot be found. Tomcat does not come with JPA support out of the box. Either use TomEE, or add the JPA related (and probably further) JARs to the tomcat's lib folder (/usr/share/tomcat7/lib in your case), or add them to the web applications lib folder when deploying the WAR file.

Remember that if you add the JARs to tomcat's lib folder, they will be shared by all applications that you deploy.

For an overview of how web/enterprise applications are made up, see http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/packaging.htm for example.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add Hibernate or other JPA implementation to classPath or... use Spring.